# Making a supervisor process in C

Tags: c

I want to make a supervisor process in c which controls the startup of some other processes, keep an eye on all the processes (previously started by itself) and deal with any error like if any of the process terminates manage all I/O errors for that process and restart that process with same context and also from the termination point. May also try to solve error behind the termination.
I search a lot but found nothing good. I found that there is supervisor control in Erlang. i want to do the same in C. 
I think of two ways to do this(keep an eye on the termination of the process):

1. Using Signals: Further there are two ways:

   > a)To use a polling protocol from supervisor and check periodically whether process is fine     or not.
   >   b)To handle all the signals in non-supervisor processes andd notify the supervisor if any killer signal appers.
2. Use Process Accounting: As defined in [Stevens - (pg250)](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZWJCvrVQUwAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) whenever a process terminates a record will be written in the accounting file. I can make the supervisor this accounting file driven. Whenever any change occurs it will check if one of our process is terminated and handles it.

*What I want is any information regarding this supervisor process as there is very little on the net about it.*

Comment: This question seems insanely broad.

Comment: I agree with millimoose, but you could start by looking at SIGCHLD, the signal your process will receive when one of its children dies.  Detecting crashed programs and restarting them will be relatively easy, things like fixing the problem resuming the program where it went wrong will prove a whole lot harder, or even close to impossible.  Also check out inter process communication because these mechanisms allow you to establish a "richer" dialog between supervisor and supervised programs - and eg verify that the supervised program isn't just hanging on a system call.

Comment: I am not asking for how to do. What I am asking is various ideas. Like accounting and signaling to keep an eye. One more example - system, exex,fork to start other process. I am just asking for various guidelines that I can use. I hope this must be done in past. So I am asking for any sources, experience or anything.

Comment: Could you outline your actual problem (if there is one), what are you trying to do with your supervisor? Is there a clear server-client relationship? Why do you think it's easier to divide the problem into separate processes?

Comment: No there is no server client relation. What i want to do is to handle different functionality from different processes and want to make sure that no error will occur

Comment: If the processes are all child processes of your "supervisor", you need one of the wait/wait3/waitpid functions. Plus possibly getrusage. But first ignore (or catch) SIGCHLD

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, there are a couple of things you can do.

## Managing Children

**Signals**

Pros:

- Easy, automatically asynchronous
- Built into every POSIX system
- Built into C
- Allow small amounts of control over the child if the child follows conventions for the actions of signals (`SIGHUP`: Reload config, `SIGTERM`: Controlled shutdown, `SIGINT`: Terminate/Ignore, `SIGKILL`: Terminate (no option about that), etc.)

Cons:

- Inaccurate
- Signals can only convey very basic ideas with no extra data
- Signal delivery is *not guarantied*
- Signals can get delayed easly, and the only one that you can really depend on being delivered under high load is `SIGKILL`
- Only two user defined action signals: `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`

**Accounting**

Pros:

- Same as signals, because getting the notice about a dead child is done through the parent receiving `SIGCHLD`

Cons:

- Same as signals
- Very little control. You can know when a child terminates, and you can restart it. No extra data, and unless you use signals in conjunction, even *less* control.

**IPC (and UNIX domain sockets)**

Pros:

- Reliable
- Rich. You can define as complicated a protocol as you want over IPC (maybe even full HTTP), and you can also just share raw memory.
- Efficient
- POSIX standardized
- You define the protocol -- send messages for what the superviser needs to know, and only that. You can tell the supervisor anything you need to.

Cons:

- Requires *large* modification to the watched process, which may be imposible.
- Requires you to invent your own protocol, which can be hard.
- Lot more code.

## Restricting Children

This is just a note. If you are using the standard `fork`(or `vfork`)/`exec` you can also restrict child usage of resources. So here's the psudocode:

```
if(fork() != 0)
{
  setrlimit(...); //Set the resource limits of the child. Look at `man 2 setrlimit`
  exec..(...);
}
```

`setrlimit` let's you set the limit on how much wall clock CPU the process can have, how much memory, how many files, etc. If the process exceeds, it is killed by `SIGXCPU`.

---

Here are a couple of things you should look into:

- `setrlimit`'s [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)
- A *great* [free ebook](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/advanced-linux-programming.pdf) on Linux programming. Take a look at the chapter on IPC.
- [`init`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) on Wikipedia
- OSX/BSD's [`launchd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) on Wikipedia

All in all, I have to suggest that you use IPC. And if you can't modify the code you want to supervise, you can still do something. if you can get status, or even better, control a process from it's STDOUT and STDIN, take a look at the C stdlib's [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) and what it's built on, POSIX's [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).

Answer (score 0):

With Stevens' *Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment* you should be settled.

If you want some examples of similar programs, have a look at Linux [sysvinit](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/sysvinit/trunk/src/?root=sysvinit) and maybe other variants like Apple's [launchd](http://opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-392.38/launchd/src/) or the BSD variants of init. Another example is inet.d, the internet super server. ([Source from Apple](http://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-115/inetd.tproj/) or [xinit.d](http://www.xinetd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/xinetd/))